# Date picker Year range with data-attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I am working in MVC 3.
I am working with **DatePicker**. In the DatePicker I am using year range on multiple textboxes. The code for that is:-

```
$('#textbox1Id').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: -10:+10
})
```

Now i am converting this sample into a function that accepts certain parameter as :-

```
function initializeDatePickerWithChangingMonthYear(minYearRange, maxYearRange) {
$('.YearRangeDatePicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: minYearRange:maxYearRange
});
}
```

I want to use data-attributes to pass different range on different textboxes in the same view. How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="YearRangeDatePicker" data-minrange="-10" data-maxrange="+10" />
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.YearRangeDatePicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: $(this).data('minrange')+':'+$(this).data('maxrange')
    });
})
```

Comment: One problem with this solution is how would it detect which textbox is being clicked now?

Comment: `$(this)` will represent `current textbox element`

Comment: Let me try this. I will get back to you in few minutes.

Comment: @vishal yes to get `$(this)` and its `data`

Comment: I am facing a problem in this one, if any of the attributes is zero then it doesn't work

Comment: `check` if any `attribute` is `zero` then `set default values` like `-10+':'+10`